# WCF: How to log raw xml message contents manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, asp-classic

I have a simple classic ASP website that calls SOAP API using WCF.
For debugging I need to log XML message contents manually into separate log files.

For example, the 12/23/18_34.txt file contains the XML request that was sent at 18:34 on 12/23.
I have read through many articles that log WCF XML messages and found these 2 methods.

1. Using the MessageLogging feature.
2. Using the IClientMessageInspector.

I could do log using the first method, but doing that I couldn't save the message contents to separate files with specific names. 
So I tried the second method, but it's not working and I can't find what's wrong.

As the current project is a classic ASP website and has no namespace, I am not sure how to set the value for the type attribute in the `web.config` file.
I managed to add it by creating a separate dll file that has `BehaviorExtensionElement` and copy it to the current project's `Bin` folder.

```
<add name="logXmlBehavior" type="MessageLogger.MessageLoggerBehaviorExtensionElement, MessageLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```

```
public class MessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

            var fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_HHmm");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText($"C:/Logs/Symmetry/{fileName}_response.txt", buffer.CreateMessage().ToString());
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();

            var fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_HHmm");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText($"C:/Logs/Symmetry/{fileName}_post.txt", buffer.CreateMessage().ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my MessageLogger class, but it doesn't log anything.

How can I add the `BehaviorExtensionElement` to a classic ASP website without a separate DLL?
And why is my current logger not working?

PS: The website is hosted using IIS.

Comment: did you get any exception when you run the application? could you share how you call WCF service from classic asp? under which identity your application pool is running? try to set the application pool identity to the network service or local system. also enable a detailed error message in iis for classic asp [link](https://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippets seem that there is no problem. Please refer to my example.
**MessageLogger class.**

```
    public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            string displayText = $"the client has received the reply:\n{reply}\n";
            Console.Write(displayText);
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            string displayText = $"the client send request message:\n{request}\n";
            Console.WriteLine(displayText);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Endpoint Behavior to be applied on the client service endpoint.

```
public class AuthBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType => typeof(AuthBehavior);
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }
        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            ClientMessageLogger inspector = new ClientMessageLogger();
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }
        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new AuthBehavior();
        }
    }
```

Then I register the endpoint behavior in the extension section and apply it on the automatically generated client service endpoint.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <!--apply it on the endpoint-->
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1300/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="authBehavior" />
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="authBehavior">
            <authbehavior />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
          <!--like yours, namespace.class,assembly-->
          <add name="authbehavior" type="Client3.AuthBehavior,Client3,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Eventually,  the console application properly logs the message when sending a request to the server.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        //client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new AuthBehavior());
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

**Result.**
[image]
Besides, I think the WCF trace also could complete this task logging the communication message. Just add the below configuration, check the `mylogs.svclog` file in the bin folder.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xmlLog" initializeData="myLogs.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.70:1300/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.